Driving a power MOSFET successfully
I have recently purchased this power MOSFET for a project (dump load resistor):
https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/mosfets/6867852?gb=s
Alongside this I have bought a MOSFET driver see link:
https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/gate-drivers/9113029P?gb=s
Upon second look I'm not sure how to wire this up successfully. I was planning to power the mosfet driver using an external 24V DC power supply. Could someone explain how I do this successfully as all the configurations in the data sheet seem to use the input from the load? I am also unsure where to feed the source.


Why are those capacitors wired in series, and why are there only six shown when it says nine?

I believe you've got it right. 24V is fairly close to the maximum mosfet gate voltage of 30. I might go down to 20.
Notice that you will be connecting the low side of your bridge rectifier to gnd. You will have to be vary careful how you do this to ensure you don't force any large currents through tiny ground wires.
Unless you absolutely know what you're doing (which you don't), I would consider the whole drive circuit, including the power supply and digital input wire to be high voltage for safety purposes. If you want to safely interface with the circuit, use an optoisolator to control the gate driver.

24V is fairly close to the maximum mosfet gate voltage of 30. The gate drive voltage is internally limited to 15V by the driver IC.
